# MySQL Workbench 1064 error in syntax

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

MySQL Workbench created this code, not me. I just used the GUI.

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
ALTER TABLE `isometr1_keyboard`.`records` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_records_layout_id`
  FOREIGN KEY ()
  REFERENCES `isometr1_keyboard`.`layouts` ()
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
  REFERENCES `isometr1_keyboard`.`layouts` ()
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDAT' at line 3
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `isometr1_keyboard`.`records` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_records_layout_id`
  FOREIGN KEY ()
  REFERENCES `isometr1_keyboard`.`layouts` ()
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

I don't understand where the error is. Also don't understand why the GUI is creating code that is buggy.

Did I make a mistake?

Comment: Well, yes.  The empty parentheses require one or more commas.

Comment: Never mind. The data types of the columns were not matching. I wish the error message said this.

Comment: You didn't select any source or target columns for the foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

The data types of the columns were not matching. This caused MySQL Workbench to create improperly formed code.